# How to continuesly fetch data from mysql with restarting Activity

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm a beginner and im working on an Android app that fetch data from mysql.
It's fetching the data that is present in mysql.
Problem is that if any update is made in to database, i have to restart the app in order to get the latest result.
i tried restarting activity but its not good approach.

```
String msg="";
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        String result = "Database connection success\n";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from android");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();


            while (rs.next()) {

                //result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                // result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getString(1) + "\n";
                result += rs.getString("hi") + "\n";
                // result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            }
            tv.setText(result);


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        msg = "CONNECTION problem";
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: how the update look like?

Comment: its like entering new value let say any name in table

Comment: can you share it please

Comment: what ?? database? i locally added names in table (hi) and i have a database named android

Comment: the update code i mean

Comment: @YCF_L updates are made in databse